# Kotlin List of List

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

I'm missing something here, and I cannot find the solution on my own, it seems (at least not within reasonable time).

I'm trying to create a 2-dimensional List, using MutableList, since each entry contains a string, an int and a boolean.

I'm creating the list entries conmtaining the data like this:

```
var workEntry = mutableListOf("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true)
```

Then I try creating a list of that object and more of the same:

```
var work = mutableListOf(mutableListOf("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true), mutableListOf("Del og Hel", 20, false))
```

That seems to work, sort of...

However, if I access the list elements, I'm unable to access them like this:

```
[x][x]
```

If I access the first level list, it contains all the elements of the entry:

```
var x = work[0].toString()  -> This yields [Knus og Knask AS, 100, true]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var y = work[0][0].toString()    <--- the second [0] doesn't exist.
```

Why is this? What am I missing? The reason I want a 2-d List is to access each element like in a table. I don't want to use any string logic for separating the elements in the "row".

Even simpler:

```
var temprow = mutableListOf("a", 10, true)
var temptable = mutableListOf<Any>(temprow)
```

var a1 = temptable[0][0] -> yields "Unresolved reference....No get method providing array access.

As long as people are voting down, or voting to close, the question without offering as much as a comment, no answers will be upvoted or accepted for this question. Those who've been helpful may thank those people for not getting their cred.

Comment: On my machine, your code works as expected. What `println(y)` prints?

Comment: I'm not able to to it. work[0][0] is marked with "Unresolved reference. ... No get method providing array access.

Comment: What version of Kotlin do you use?

Comment: Latest, as far as I know. I update as soon as I get a notice.

Comment: The second example isn't correct - it should be `var temptable = mutableListOf<MutableList<Any>>(temprow)`

Comment: Can't reproduce on Kotlin playground - https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjMxIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhciB3b3JrRW50cnkgPSBtdXRhYmxlTGlzdE9mKFwiS251cyBvZyBLbmFzayBBU1wiLCAxMDAsIHRydWUpXG4gICAgdmFyIHdvcmsgPSBtdXRhYmxlTGlzdE9mKG11dGFibGVMaXN0T2YoXCJLbnVzIG9nIEtuYXNrIEFTXCIsIDEwMCwgdHJ1ZSksIG11dGFibGVMaXN0T2YoXCJEZWwgb2cgSGVsXCIsIDIwLCBmYWxzZSkpXG4gICAgdmFyIHggPSB3b3JrWzBdLnRvU3RyaW5nKClcbiAgICB2YXIgeSA9IHdvcmtbMF1bMF0udG9TdHJpbmcoKSBcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKHkpXG59IiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiJ9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this question myself, in answer to those who are voting down the question, or even to CLOSE it (!), without having the decency or personal integrity to comment on it.

This is a huge problem with StackOverflow. There is absolutely no good reason why you should be able to vote down something without having to post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

```
var temprow = mutableListOf("a", 10, true)
var temptable = mutableListOf<List<Any>>(temprow)
```

You need to specify the type as `List<Any>` or `MutableList<Any>`. That way when you access the elements like `temptable[0]` it returns a `List<Any>` which has array access.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works.

```
fun main(){

    val arrayOrg = Array(10) { arrayOf(Triple("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true), Triple("Knus og Knask AS", 200, true)) }

    println(arrayOrg[0][1])
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But I'm more inclined to use List or similar than Array.

Answer (score 0):

I used kotlin with version `1.3.50` and could **not** reproduce your error. Code syntax which I tried:

```
val work = mutableListOf(mutableListOf("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true), mutableListOf("Del og Hel", 20, false))
val result = work[0][0] // compiles

---------------

val work2 = listOf(listOf("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true), listOf("Del og Hel", 20, false))
val result2 = work2[0][0] // compiles

---------------   

val work3 = listOf(Triple("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true))
work3[0].first // compiles
```

### Checklist

- Do you have the latest (stable) kotlin version?
- Have you tried executing this code on another machine (from a coworker / friend / online EDI) ?
- Did you override the type of your lists yourself? `mutableListOf<Any>` would not enable you to access any index! `List<List<*>>` would work and would return `Any` for `[0][0]` (which is not a good way to continue). If you let kotlin detect the type itself, it generates `List<List<{Comparable{Boolean & Int & String}> & java.io.Serializable}>>`.
- Rethink your choice of implementation and go for a List with custom data class (or Triple). That way your index calls are type safe. `listOf(Triple("Knus og Knask AS", 100, true))`